# MPAndroidChart library - Displaying yAxis Labels in decimal for small range in BarChart Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am trying to display yAxis values in Decimal format where value starts from 7.35, and ends in 7.4.

To set values for YAxis following code is written:

```
val yAxis = chart.axisLeft

yAxis.valueFormatter = YAxisLabelFormatter()

yAxis.axisMinimum = 7.35

yAxis.isGranularityEnabled = true

yAxis.labelCount = 5

chart.axisRight.setDrawZeroLine(true)

chart.data = combinedData

chart.invalidate()
```

YAxisLabelFormatter class goes here:

```
class YAxisLabelFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
        var label = "0"
        if (value > 0) {
            label = value.toInt().toString()
        }
        return label
    }
}
```

With the above code, Bar chart is plotted but YAxis Label displayed as blank for small ranges. For bigger ranges like 7 to 10, YAxis Label displayed properly but with Integer values. Any suggestions how to display YAxis Labels in Decimal for small ranges.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after following code changes:

```
class YAxisDecimalLabelFormatter() : IAxisValueFormatter {
    private val mFormat: DecimalFormat = DecimalFormat("#.##")
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
        return mFormat.format(value)
    }
}


val yAxis = chart.axisLeft

yAxis.valueFormatter = YAxisDecimalLabelFormatter()

yAxis.axisMinimum = 7.35

yAxis.setLabelCount(5, false)

chart.axisRight.setDrawZeroLine(true)

chart.data = combinedData

chart.invalidate()
```